# Is there a way to combine ADFS and non-ADFS authentication?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, active-directory, adfs

How can I combine an ADFS based and a user database based authentication methods into a single process or at least result in a single User object with claims and roles so I can use AuthorizeAttribute?

I have two ASP.Net MVC applications that I need to combine into a single application, we're eliminating duplicated functionality. Normally this would be a snap, but this one isn't. The problem is the user authentication App 1 uses ADFS and our AD accounts for authentication. The other application (App 2) uses a user database with salted and hashed passwords. Not all users in App 2 have, and will never have, AD accounts. That is corporate policy and not negotiable.

In another application I was able to add additional claims to the User object for dynamically named claims and a custom AuthorizeAttribute. I'm sure I'll need to perform the same action on the App 2 accounts, but I'm not sure how to integrate the two styles seamlessly.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest way is to use [identityserver 4](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/) to handle the DB authentication and then federate ADFS and identityserver.

Or use a SaaS Identity provider like Auth0 for the DB side. Then federate ADFS and Auth0.